# Get width of each column cell of first row of a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table lets suppose any random table. Now i need to get width of a every cell of a column of the first row of the table. Values has to be stored in an array.

Comment: If you tried with any code, please share with us. then we can help you.

Comment: Okay! How does your table look like? Did you try something? We can't help you until you demonstrate the efforts, and at least post your existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution.

I would request you to post your code for better understanding.

```js
var width_details = [];
$('tr:nth-child(1) > td').each(function(){
  width_details.push($(this).width());
});

console.log(width_details.sort(function(a, b){return a-b}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>342342342</td>
      <td>aa</td>
      <td>safsdertert34543543534</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second Row</td>
      <td>asadasdasdasdsadadasdasasda</td>
      <td>ee</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: now i need to add the same width to the table head. how do i achieve this?? can you help me?

Comment: @AayushRajopadhyaya adding the same width to the `th` is simple. `$('th').each(function(){ $(this).css('width', val); });